# Unable to retrieve data from mongodb on meteor / shopify polaris

Tags: database, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I've a problem, I have create a link between my website meteor and this database mongodb and I can write in it. However when I try to retrieve this data I have nothing. I use ReactJs/Shopify polaris/meteor so i don't use html.

When i use this for get data:

```
import { Workpackages} from '../../api/stores/listMongo'
var work = Workpackages.find().fetch();
console.log(work);
```

i observe this in the console:

```
[]
   length: 0
   <prototype>: Array []
```

But my workpackages collection  have 63 documents.
Do you have any idea to resolve my problem?

Thanks you

(ps:listmongo:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Workpackages = new Mongo.Collection('workpackage');
```

publication.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Stores } from '../stores';
import {Vues, Appartients, Groupes, Personnes, Workpackages, Entites, Possedes, Droits, Taches } from '../listMongo'

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    var work = Workpackages.find().fetch();
    console.log(work);
    return work;
  })
  Meteor.publish('Stores', function () {
    return Stores.find({ owner: this.userId }, { fields: { token: 0 } });
  });
  Personnes.allow({
    'insert': function (idP,name,pwd) {
      return true; }
  })
  Groupes.allow({
    'insert': function (idG,libelle) {
      return true; },
  })
  Appartients.allow({
    'insert': function (idP,idG) {
      return true; }
  })
  Vues.allow({
    'insert': function (idW,idG) {
      return true; }
  })
  Workpackages.allow({
    'insert': function (idW,type,name,presence) {
      return true; }
  })
  Workpackages.find({}).fetch();
  Entites.allow({
    'insert': function (idE,typeE,nameE) {
      return true; },
  })
  Possedes.allow({
    'insert': function (idG,idD) {
      return true; }
  })
  Droits.allow({
    'insert': function (idD,libelleD) {
      return true; }
  })
  Taches.allow({
    'insert': function (id,hours,dCreate,description,idP,idW,idE) {
      return true; }
  })
  Meteor.publish("groupe", function () {
    console.log(Groupe.find());
    return Groupe.find();
  }); 
}
```

)

Comment: Is this code on the client or on the server? Please also add your publications / subscription code.

Comment: What do you mean by publications and subscriptions? And this code is on the server

Comment: Pub / sub is used to manage what documents data is sent from server to the client. In your case not relevant (but highly relevant for Meteor Apps in general). Please put your code `var work = Workpackages.find().fetch();` in a `Meteor.startup` block. Does it work?

Comment: There is an evolution! In my console i've list of workpackages collections, how can i pass this list in my display page? I've edit for add my publication.js where i put the startup (in the display pages he doesn't work)

Comment: Your collection name is `workpackage` (lower case, singular form) so I'm guessing `var work` should equal to `workpackage.find().fetch();`?

Comment: i've doing this: export const Workpackages = new Mongo.Collection('workpackage'); so when i create var work i call "Workpackage" and not "workpackage"

Comment: In Meteor you need to subscribe (client-side) to a publication (server-side) to retrieve the data. The subscription is not immediate and must be wrapped in a reactive container, typically [`Tracker.autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun)